# Django query - How to get concurrent number of records in 5 minutes span of time?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm very new in Django and Sql. Sorry for this basic question.

I have below model with Django + PostgreSql to record activity start/stop time;

```
class Test(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('test_session_id',)

    test_session_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, null=True)
    started_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    finished_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to figure out how many tests is running in every 5 minutes span of time.
If below four session exists, could you please guide me how to write Django queryset to achive below result?

```
Sample Data
====
Test#1 11:33 ~ 12:17
Test#2 11:44 ~ 12:51
Test#3 12:08 ~ 12:19
Test#4 12:21 ~ 12:55
```

```
Expected query result
===
11:30 => 0
11:35 => 1
11:40 => 1
11:45 => 2
...
12:10 => 3
12:15 => 3
12:20 => 1
12:25 => 2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function on views.py. I tested It seems working.

Function:

```
import datetime
import pytz

def testFunction0(dMain):
    testObjects = Test.objects.all()
    countedTest = 0

    for test in testObjects:
        if test.started_at < dMain and test.finished_at > dMain:
            countedTest = countedTest + 1

    return countedTest
```

Use like this:

```
print(testFunction0(dMain=pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 5, 12, 15))))
```

Comment: Do you want python script for testing every 5 min. for this ?

Comment: Thanks marlonjd. I though there exist some DB queries for easy coding. As I think looping though the whole records looks like expensive task.

Comment: If you satisfied about the answer please check as answer. Have fun